# Building JavaScript within php

Tags: php, javascript

i been now hanging on this for like a hour and cant finde the problem. Its driving me crazy

```
$script .=nl().'$(this).html("<img src="'.CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif').'" />");';
```

i get the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list


$(this).html("<img src="https://cdn.connexservice.com/icons/loading/loading5.gif...
```

and the arrow showson the h of the https..
I must been missing a ' or a " somewhere...
Hopefully some one got a better eye on this..

bah.. quick edit, found the problem, but , it wont show the gif.

```
$script .=nl(). '$(this).html("<img src=\''.CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif').'\' />");';
```

this is shown in the source code:

```
$(this).html("<img src=\"https://cdn.connexservice.com/icons/loading/loading5.gif\" />");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your HTML using `\`:

```
$script .=nl().'$(this).html("<img src=\"'.CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif').'\" />");';
```

Comment: i found the problem to, got any idea why the image wont show?

Comment: Does the `<img>` element get correctly added to the DOM? What is the reference of `$(this)`?

Comment: semmes something got cahsed in my browesr it works now thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your quotation marks:

```
$script .= nl() . '$(this).html("<img src=\"' . CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif') . '\" />");';
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply proper escaping everywhere, I prefer writing it out like this:

```
$script .= nl() . sprintf('$(this).html(%s);',
        json_encode(sprintf('<img src="%s" />', CDN('/icons/loading/loading5.gif')))
);
```

I'm using two `sprintf()` calls; the first is to build the HTML string, the second is to build the JavaScript code.

Additionally it uses `json_encode()` to make sure the string is properly escaped.